# How do I prevent the last sentence in each MS Word page from breaking to the next page?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I want the last sentence in the page, to be a non-breaking sentence in MS Word.

"Page break before" option does not work for me. Because, It moves the whole paragraph to the next page. I want to break the page down just right after the last punctuation mark at the end of each page. In other words, sentences should not overflow to the next page.

So, I think I need to detect the last punctuation mark in the page and insert a [Enter]/[Page Break] after that. How can I do this in VB.NET.

Or any other simpler solution?

Comment: It could be that setting [ParagraphFormat.WidowControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphformat.widowcontrol) to `False` would help you get the result you want; you might still need to use "page break before".

Answer (score 0):

How much text is shown on a page is determined dynamically by Word, based on the margin settings and the current printer-driver. Word calculates the layout dynamically and it's not possible to force specific content into a page, as is possible with page layout software. Increasing the margin settings would be a possible approach, but this would apply to the entire document or entire `Section`.

To prevent single lines from being split off, Word has the following settings in the Paragraph Format/Line and Page Breaks dialog box, with equivalents in the object model:

- Window/Orphan control (active by installation default): - `Paragraph.Format.WidowControl` (boolean)

> True if the first and last lines in the specified paragraph remain on
>   the same page as the rest of the paragraph when Word repaginates the
>   document.

- Keep lines together - Paragraph.Format.KeepTogether

> True if all lines in the specified paragraphs remain on the same page
>   when Microsoft Word repaginates the document.

The only way to force a page's content would be to put the content in a Drawing SuatoShape `TextBox` (`Shape.Text = msoTextBox`). Draw the text box large enough for all the content - it can go outside a margin setting - and insert the content. But note that Word's normal editing behavior will not be the same. For example, adding or deleting content on a previous page will not change the content in the text box and could end up "kicking" it to another page, entirely, with unwanted white space on other pages.